# Adding style to active link with ActiveClassName and CSS Module in Gatsby is not working

Tags: css, reactjs, gatsby, react-css-modules

I'm facing an issue when I try to implement this:https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/gatsby-link/#add-custom-styles-for-the-currently-active-link using the ActiveClassName option.

I have created a navbar.js component which contains the links:

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "gatsby";

import navbarStyles from "./navbar.module.css";

export default function Navbar() {
  return (
    <nav className={navbarStyles.navbar}>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/contact/" activeClassName="active">
            Contact
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/blog/" activeClassName="active">
            Blog
          </Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
}
```

and Styles are in a navbar.module.css (where I've defined a 'active' class) :

```
/* navbar */
nav ul li a {
    color: #FFF;
}
nav ul li a.active {
    color: #000;
}
```

My navbar link default color is correct #FFF
My link is correctly updated with the active class when I go to the corresponding page, eg. :

```
<a aria-current="page" class="active" href="/contact/">Contact</a>
```

But .active style is never applied to the active link :( (Black color)

Strange thing here, when I extract the '.active' CSS from navbar.module.css and put it in my global.css file, things are working!

How can I make things work keeping my styles in the CSS modules?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

> Strange thing here, when I extract the '.active' CSS from
> navbar.module.css and put it in my global.css file, things are
> working!

Clearly, your styles are being overriten somewhere in your CSS code. Check the importation of the CSS assets and inspect the element to check from where is the current styling is taken (check the computed tab in the inspector).

Your code is perfectly valid and your CSS rule too, despite mixing [CSS modules and CSS standard styling](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/styling/). You can also try something like:

```
      <Link to="/blog/" activeClassName={navbarStyles.active}>
        Blog
      </Link>
```

Comment: Hi! When I inspect elements, I can see that my standard 'link' styles are those from navbar.module.css but the '.active' style only work when set in global.css ! Also tried activeClassName={navbarStyles.active} but this results in a incorect link `<a aria-current="page" class="{navbarStyles.active}" href="/contact/">Contact</a>` I'm pretty sure to miss something simple here :(

Comment: I add a precision, I've tried to put both `.active` and `nav ul li a.active` selectors in both navbar.module.css and global.css files, each time with different colors. The problem is only for this active state!

Comment: Well, if you use CSS standard style (styling with `.active{color: red}`) for example, you should import your CSS file  with  `import from "./yourStyles.css"`. I think your issue comes from mixing stuff

Comment: Since you are importing CSS modules but applying a CSS class, it will only work if somewhere in the code the CSS file is imported (like in the global)

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you're using `activeClassName="active"` meanwhile you should be using the mapped class instead: `activeClassName={navbarStyles.active}`. And it seams that you don't have any class called `navbar` but you're trying to apply that style to the `nav` element: `className={navbarStyles.navbar}`.

But I suggest using [patch-styles](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-patch-styles?file=src/App.js) package, which introduces a more declarative way of applying styles. It's patching `className`s instead of you.

You can use the `PatchStyles` with `extraParams={'activeClassName'}` to make it patch `activeClassName`s too. See the [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-patch-styles?file=src/pages/FirstPage.module.css) example for more details. (In the StackBlitz example click on the `First Page` link and see how the active style is being activated automatically).